# Best Ruby data structure for organizing the NFL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures

I'm trying to organize NFL teams into data structures in Ruby. My goal is to easily query to know that the Baltimore Ravens are the AFC (conference) and the AFC North (division).

I would also like to easily see which teams are in the AFC (16 of them) and which teams are in the AFC North (4 of them).

Right now I'm using arrays on arrays but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

With the way my data is structured right now, I have to puts nfl[0][0][0] to print out Baltimore Ravens (first 0 is AFC/NFC, second 0 is conference and third 0 is division). This seems to be way too complicated.

Any help or insight would be amazing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They should be classes with relationships rather than trying to leverage the native ruby data structures.  Even if the classes don't DO things, you get a lot of natural sounding code out of rails relationships.

I'd much rather say:

```
team = Team.find_by_name("Ravens")
```

than

```
team = nfl[0][0][0]
```

You also get potentially other helpful calls for nearly free:

```
team = Team.find_by_city("Baltimore")   # also gets you the ravens
```

and when you want to grab all the teams for a division:

```
all_nfc_teams = Division.find_by_name("NFC").teams
```

which is far more readable than

```
all_nfc_teams = nfl[0][1]
```

I can imagine all sorts of other helpful semantics, like finding all of the week 4 games for the AFC, or ordering a division of teams by wins and losses.  You can define scopes on Teams that would allow you to retrieve collections of teams with very clear semantics.

```
all_nfc_teams = Team.nfc
```

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is subjective. It also depends on the nature of the organizational entities.

Do divisions and/or conferences do anything other than hold teams? If so, then they should be classes.

Otherwise hashes are probably fine, although I might encapsulate them in a convenience class, to hide the hash structures, provide named-team access, etc.

Comment: NFL holds conferences, conferences hold divisions, divisions hold teams, teams hold statistics about themselves

Comment: @ZackShapiro The question was more like "Do they do anything *other* than hold objects?" Hashes can hold objects and have well-understood semantics. If the containers don't need to know/do anything domain-specific, then it's a matter of style, convenience, and preference. Personally, I'd make classes, for clarity, and future extension.